# Change jupyter notebook theme using jupyterthemes

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I installed and set up jupyterthemes but it only highlight code output not the entire notebook theme.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee7yK.png)

code used:
install jupyterthemes in command prompt:
pip install jupyterthemes
set up a theme:
jt -t onedork -T -N -kl